# Passing Journal Line between form

Tags: axapta, x++

I am having a program that deal with passing Journal Line to another Form. The program consist a button on Payment Journal that calls out a Form to let the user to select General Journal they want to settle and insert details to the Payment Journal. The code for passing Journal Line have an issue when the selected line is newly created. The Journal Line is either not passing any value or selecting default value to the other form when there is an asterisk as shown :

[image: Selected Journal with asterisk]

Found out that the Journal Lines is not selected and recId is 0 at form B
[image: Journal Line is not pass to another form]
This was fix by having a  `LedgerJournalTrans.write()` on to p of my `clicked` code which looks like this:

```
{
Args args;
FormRun formRun;
;


    LedgerJournalTrans.write();//add to fix unable to capture Table, but create unsaved Voucher issue
    if (LedgerJournalTable.ledgerJournalName().LHAmBankCBPS)
    {
    //args= new Args(formstr(CBPSInvoiceLookup));
        args= new Args();
        args.record(LedgerJournalTrans);
        args.parm(LedgerJournalTrans.Voucher);
        args.name(formstr(CBPSGJLookup));
        formRun=classFactory.formRunClass(args);
        formRun.init();
        formRun.run();
        formRun.wait();
        formRun.detach();
        super();
        ledgerjournaltrans_ds.executeQuery();
        ledgerjournaltrans_ds.refresh();

        this.update();



    }
    else
    {
        throw info(strfmt("%1","Only CBPS journal able to use this button"));
    }

     // mark the number as used


    info(strfmt("%1","End program"));

}
```

However with the additional  `LedgerJournalTrans.write()` code, this error code appear after finished the job and attempt to create a new line:

[image: New number cannot be assign]

Is there any alternative way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, instead of using `LedgerJournalTrans.write()` using `LedgerJournalTrans_DS.write` will solve both problems.

Not sure if this is the correct way to explain using `LedgerJournalTrans_DS.write` can perform Save and flush out the temporary data which Lock the Voucher number from creating new Voucher number.

When the journal is created Journal line is not physically created that the system unable to select the Journal Number. Hence to do so, the Journal need to be save in order to let the journal to be selected